# How to create a reference to a parsed field in a query in AWS Athena?

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

In this query, the `time` field is parsed with `parse_datetime` 2 times:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('HOUR', parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z')),
  *
FROM
  logs
WHERE
  parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z') BETWEEN timestamp '2020-05-14 19:00' AND timestamp '2020-05-14 23:59'
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT
  parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z') as parsed_time,
  date_trunc('HOUR', parsed_time),
  *
FROM
  logs
WHERE
  parsed_time BETWEEN timestamp '2020-05-14 19:00' AND timestamp '2020-05-14 23:59'
```

It is possible to parse `time` only once?

Comment: Have you considered a sub query?) also can you try to reference parses column in `where` clause by a consecutive number, i.e. 1 since it is first from the top. I know it works for `group by` and `order by` not sure about `where` clause though)

Comment: Can you write an answer with an example?

Comment: See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61815998/6147064) from Piotr Findeisen. That is exactly what I meant by "using a subquery"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per SQL specification, `WHERE` clause cannot refer to the projections in the `SELECT` clause, it can only refer to columns provided by the `FROM`.

- you can repeat the expression in full in the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE parse_datetime(...) BETWEEN ...`
- you can wrap the query as a subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT parse_datetime(....) as parsed_time, ...
  FROM ...
)
WHERE parsed_time BETWEEN ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment, I wrote as an answer because my score was not enough. can you change it like this and try it?;

```
SELECT
 parse_datetime(time,'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS''Z') as parsed_time,
 logs.*
FROM
 logs
HAVING parsed_time BETWEEN timestamp '2020-05-14 19:00' AND timestamp '2020-05-14 23:59'
```

Comment: Thanks, same result, didn't work, there are no results. Maybe this is an AWS Athena specific issue.

Comment: I suppose it comes from type mismatch. parse_datetime function returns timestamp with time zone, but the bottom condition uses timestamp type. Can you try date_parse function instead of parse_datetime to separate issues?

Comment: Per SQL specification, `HAVING`  implies global groping if no `GROUP BY` is specified, it is not an "equivalent of `WHERE`". Older Presto versions had this implemented correct, but it's fixed in recent releases (Presto 330+, https://prestosql.io/download.html)